# jQuery drag to scroll disable

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm a little stuck at the moment with some html/css/jquery mixture.

Basically i've got this setup.

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden">
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

so my parent div acts as a frame, with content within it that will be scrolled to using scrollto plugin.

however I've got an issue that if someone clicks down in the frame area and drag their mouse, it scrolls the div around.

how can i disable this behaviour? I've already used the scroll event and preventDefault but thats not working for drag scrolling.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Owen

Comment: Isn't the purpose of that plugin to make things easy for touch devices (i.e. drag scrolling)? Could you please clarify why you need the plugin? Otherwise, you could probably get what you need by just setting overflow: auto on your parent div that you mentioned

Comment: sorry I didnt realise my code wasnt showing. Imagine I had 3 columns within my inner div and a seperate navigation, i could use scrollto to do like $('#innerdiv').scrollto(800, axis: x) then it can scroll to each section of the inner div

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Either don't use a plugin and just use jquery's animate() function to give a new left position on the inner div, or...

Try scrollto's "children" projects: [SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) and [LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html). It sounds like those are more meant for navigation (using js to scroll to some position after clicking something) than physical scrolling and it sounds like thats what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, but my issue isnt with the how to scroll, its the fact with "overflow:hidden" on instead of using the scroll bar to scroll the page, you just drag the page down, or scroll your mouse wheel and its scrolled. i would like to disable this function

Comment: @OwenMelbourne I think I understand now. Could you please clarify when you want the inner div to move? On some click event? You could do this without any plugin by using jQuery.animate(). If you know the left position that you want to move the inner div to, you could just call animate and pass in the new left value.

Comment: No worries mate, I've changed the html structure so it fits the hight perfectly, thus nothing to scroll down to!